# Gap between columns with defined width

Tags: html, css, gap-system

I have to give the gap between the columns width defined width but the columns shown in a row are 2. How i can resolve?

```
<section class="container primo">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
</section>
```

the css

```
.container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 24px;
}
.container div{
                width: calc(100% /3);
}
```

the column have to be 3, but the first column of the first row is double in size